# Login to SSH twice at the same time

Tags: linux, ssh, gnome-terminal

Is there any way to setup my SSH client or my GNOME terminal or whatver so that when I SSH into a remote server it opens up TWO connections (or tabs or whatever)?

I always like to have two SSH connections to my remote servers open - one for displaying log files and another to do actual work. It bugs me that I have to login twice everytime.

Possible? Sensible? What's the verdict?!

Comment: verdict is that this aint the place to ask.

Comment: Why not just use screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  If you only have one terminal open, where would the two connection send output and get input?   You might find something like "screen" useful that lets you have multiple virtual terminals that display to a single physical terminal.  You use a key sequence to switch between them.  I use it all the time when working over a remote login to a Unix box.  It's also nice because you can re-attach to your virtual terminals if you lose your connection.

Comment: screen it is! Wow, I had absolutely no idea such a command even existed! Thanks. Logging aspect looks juicy too.